# OSX : Chrome cannot connect to .localhost-domains. Connection refused

Tags: macos, google-chrome, localhost, ipv6, ipv4

This have me stumped.

I have a local development setup running nginx + php-fpm where I'm using .localhost as working domain for each project. Yesterday Chrome stopped working with the local domains. Instead it just returns connection refused. DevTools shows the error as  `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

Accessing http://127.0.0.1 works, but of course won't work with the local projects.

Safari continues to work with .localhost.

Chrome : Version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (x86_64)
OS : macOS 11.4 (20F71)

Answer (score 0):

Tried several different things like:

- updating /etc/hosts
- clearing DNS for Chrome `chrome://net-internals/#dns`
- removing domains from `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

Solution was found after creating a netlogs from chrome://net-internals/#events and then looking at the different events. Found this:

```
t=18295 [st=0] +SOCKET_ALIVE  [dt=4]
                --> source_dependency = 5112 (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_JOB)
t=18295 [st=0]   +TCP_CONNECT  [dt=1]
                  --> address_list = ["[::1]:80","127.0.0.1:80"]
                  --> canonical_name = ""
t=18295 [st=0]      TCP_CONNECT_ATTEMPT  [dt=1]
                    --> address = "[::1]:80"
t=18296 [st=1]   -TCP_CONNECT
                  --> source_address = "[::1]:56378"
t=18296 [st=1]   +SOCKET_IN_USE  [dt=3]
                  --> source_dependency = 5111 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=18296 [st=1]      SOCKET_BYTES_SENT
                    --> byte_count = 719
t=18298 [st=3]      SOCKET_READ_ERROR
                    --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
                    --> os_error = 54
t=18299 [st=4]   -SOCKET_IN_USE
t=18299 [st=4]    SOCKET_POOL_CLOSING_SOCKET
                  --> reason = "Connection was closed when it was returned to the pool"
t=18299 [st=4] -SOCKET_ALIVE
```

Chrome seems to default to IPv6.

**Solution**
Adding `listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;` to nginx site configuration and restarting nginx.